# Mounting problem for second partition

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mount, link2sd

I am unable to mount the second partition of my SDCard using the *Link2SD* app. My phone is a *Samsung Galaxy Ace.* I enabled superuser root access also for *Link2SD,* but still it does not work. My phone is rooted and I tried everything.

What could I do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details on "everything", also possible error messages. further see [these questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=link2sd+mount+is%3Aquestion), especially [Link2sd gives “Mount script error”](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18098/16575) / [cannot mount sdext for link2sd?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29019/16575) / [Second partition can't be mounted (link2sd)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35701/16575).

Answer (score 1):

Could be more than one problem.
You could try:

```
su
mkdir /data/sdext2
mount -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/block/vold/179:2 /data/sdext2
```

1. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1568686
2. http://androidforums.com/optimus-v-all-things-root/695963-link2sd-tutorial-new-updated-version.html
3. in terminal, if you have access to:

Folders:

```
 /data/
 /dev/block/mmcblk0p2/
 /dev/block/vold/
```

Files:

```
 /system/etc/init.d/11link2sd
 /system/etc/init.d/
```